# How to use Autofac registration in an ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm migrating my ASP.NET Web API project to ASP.NET Core. I use Autofac for DI and I have the following registrations:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
```

Now, in ASP.NET Core, do I need to continue registering controllers and filters or are they automatically registered?

And secondly, what is the new way to register SignalR hubs?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this Autofac docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) is what you are after. 
Depends on the version of ASP.NET Core you use, there are different solutions illustrated in the docs.

In terms of SignalR, you could follow [this Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1), and use `Populate` method provided by Autofac to populate your service collection into `ContainerBuilder`.